# azure static web app + github = cant merge any PR, get "deployment_token was not provided", but does deploy when doing a normal commit to main

Tags: azure, github, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app

we have a pure html/js static web app, and when we commit to main, it "builds" it by deploying the html/js as they are to the static web app, and all is good.

we can happily commit to main, and the static web app gets magically deployed via the .github/workflows/azurexxx.yaml file.

However, if we want to merge a PR, it fails on a build step:

Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD / Build and Deploy Job (pull_request) Failing after 48s

The error is:

```
Run Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
/usr/bin/docker run --name c9a4a5a9e299732ab04
LOTS OF STUFF
DeploymentId: 5babc754-54b0-4694-9e7d-xxxxx

deployment_token was not provided.
The deployment_token is required for deploying content. If you'd like to continue the run without deployment, add the configuration skip_deploy_on_missing_secrets set to true in your workflow file
An unknown exception has occurred
```

what I dont know is WHY its trying to do a deployment as part of the PR, as we only have a "production" static web app, there is no "test" static web app in existence that we could build to.  How do we tell github not to try to build/deploy, and instead just merge it which will automatically kick off a build/deploy which we know works.

the yaml file is:

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_WONDERFUL_PLANT_00xxxx }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "/" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_WONDERFUL_PLANT_00xxxx }}
          action: "close"
```

the error message suggests "skip_deploy_on_missing_secrets set to true in your workflow file". How/where do we do this?  Presumably this has to go somewhere in the yaml file, but this is part of the PR (or does it use the non PR one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployment phase will be ignored for pull requests with `skip_deploy_on_missing_secrets: true`, and it will only run when there is a push to the main branch or when a pull request is closed i.e merged. Your pull requests should no longer initiate the deployment phase as a result of this setting, and the automatic build/deploy process will proceed as usual once the pull request is merged into the main branch.

**My github workflow script:-**

***I have added `skip_deploy_on_missing_secrets: true`, below output_location***

Find my complete github workflow [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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).

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_GENTLE_FOREST_087983710 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/site" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "" # Built app content directory - optional
          skip_deploy_on_missing_secrets: true
          

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_GENTLE_FOREST_087983710 }}
          action: "close"
```

Also, This error is occurring because after the PR the github action workflow cannot read your secret, Here, You need to manually download the Deployment token from Manage deployment token tab and copy it as a secret in your workflow.

[image]